# How to disable Auto Fetch in PhpStorm?

Tags: git, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

How to disable Git Auto Fetch in PhpStorm?

I think this is default function of PhpStorm, it will open a Login Popup every 5 minutes if I don't login, which really annoying.

[image]

Comment: According to the comment below, there is no auto-fetch feature (at least a year ago):
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211447#focus=Comments-27-3467826.0-0

Any chance that you have custom Git-related plugins installed and enabled?

Comment: @duck_in_hat thanks, i've searching for installed plugin, and i've found that there is installed plugin called "Git Toolbox" which is have auto fetch function, and i've disabled it. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Uncheck the `Auto fetch` option on the [GitToolBox](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox) plugin settings:

[image]